# creating group programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, event-receivers

I'm trying to create a new group by event receiver feature with this code, but when I deploy it nothing changes

```
public static void CreateSubSiteGroup(SPWeb web, string groupName, string PermissionLevel,string groupDescription)

        {
            SPUserCollection users = web.AllUsers;
            SPUser owner = web.SiteAdministrators[0];
            SPMember member = web.SiteAdministrators[0];
            SPGroupCollection groups = web.SiteGroups;
            groups.Add(groupName, member, owner, groupDescription);
            SPGroup newSPGroup = groups[groupName];
            SPRoleDefinition role = web.RoleDefinitions[PermissionLevel];
            SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(newSPGroup);
            roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(role);
            web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
            web.Update();
        }

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {

        string groupName="Donor";
        string groupDescription = "Group for Donors";
        try
        {
            using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)
            {
                CreateSubSiteGroup(web, groupName, "Full Control", groupDescription);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The very obvious mistake I can see is not to put `properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb` in using..

`using (SPWeb web = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb)` shouldn't be used.. just like `SPContext.Current.Web`, you shouldn't dispose properties.Feature.Parent (you didn't create a new object anywhere.. so you are not responsible for disposing it)

Answer (score -1):

Pls write your code

`Web.update();`

Between

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

web.update();

web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```